# Open Default page without Addressbar, Menubar & Statusbar in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, fullscreen

How can I open my Default.aspx page without Addressbar, Menubar & Statusbar?

Comment: As a potential visitor to such a site, I wish I have my freedom to see the address bar, menu bar and status bar. Don't trouble users unnecessarily. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember it's the user with an already-opened web browser that chooses to visit your website, effectively Default.aspx page, whether or not the browser is launched by you or a program while testing your website. So a bit of client-side/JavaScript "magic" is needed to modify or fake the desired result based on an already existing browser window...

Using JavaScript, you can launch a new window with those features turned off, and close the old window. For example, IE's [window.open(..) args are specified here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(VS.85).aspx).

It provides an example

```
varCustomFeatures = 'titlebar=no, status=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes, scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,left=0,top=0,height=';    
window.open(windowURL, '_blank' , varCustomFeatures,true);
```

Details may vary between browser in which case you will likely need to employ browser detection.

Comment: But in some browsers( like IE6 ) it asks a confirmation when closing that old window. Is there any method to avoid the confirmation?

Comment: No, you can't.  How would you like it if a website suddenly closed your browser?  Also, remember that the user might visit your site in Firefox with 50 tabs open.

Comment: @SLaks: Tabs is a exceptionally good point. Spawning a new windows and closing the user's main window predates tabs. Likely trying to close the old window nowadays is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

However, you can create a popup windows without the bars in Javascript using `open` method, like this:

```
open("MyPage.aspx", "MyWindow", "toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no");
```

Comment: I know with new popup windows its working, But i want to know any methods available for the default page...